# How can Jetson TX1 run in Max Performance just as Jetson TK1？

Tags: nvidia

I used max performance （CPU）code in the terminal of Jetson TK1 which is showed in eLinux.

But it goes error in TX1, which gives out IO ERROR and File no Exist. How can TX1 run in max performance？

Answer (score 0):

For TX1 there is jetson_clocks.sh in the house folder. Launch it sudo jetson_clocj.sh and receive the maximum productivity of TX1.